# The translation result should be in Column B in the same excel sheet (fruits.xlsx)

Tags: python, xlrd, goslate

1. The below code translates words that is located in the fruits.xlsx in Column A.
2. I want the output/result should be in Column B

```
import xlrd
import goslate

loc = r"C:\path\fruits.xlsx"
gs = goslate.Goslate()

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc) 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
  
for i in range(sheet.nrows): 
    print(gs.translate(sheet.cell_value(i, 0), 'de'))
    print(sheet.cell_value(i, 1)
```

I am receiving the below error

```
 return self._cell_values[rowx][colx]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Please someone help me to write my output/result in the same excel in Column B

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(sheet.nrows - 1)
```

Python indicies begin from 0, so the last row will be sheet.nrows - 1

make sure to also add the closing parenthesis to the last print statement

```
print(sheet.cell_value(i, 1))
```

Comment: this code is getting error `import xlrd
import goslate

loc = r"C:\path\fruits.xlsx"
gs = goslate.Goslate()

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

for i in range(sheet.nrows - 1):
    print(gs.translate(sheet.cell_value(i, 0), 'de'))
    print(sheet.cell_value(i, 1)`  Error is : `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`

Comment: @kumar `print(sheet.cell_value(i, 1)` should be `print(sheet.cell_value(i, 1))`